# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: Bart]
[image: Alvin]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

---

**Update: September 2017**

After several years of being a moderator on this site, [Rob](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/43) has decided to step down. Please thank him for all his help.

We'd also like to welcome [Nuno Linhares](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/33/nuno-linhares) to the team. He has graciously agreed to step up to the role.

[image: Nuno]

Comment: Congrats Bart, Rob and Gleen

Answer (score 4):

Welcome @Alvin glad to have you on board!
@Glenn thx for all the work you have done!

Comment: With great verbosity comes great responsibility, or something like that. :-P Glad to join and much thanks to Glenn as well!